Is $2$-connected $k$-regular vertex transitive graph also $3$-connected?
Assume a graph is simple and finite.
Is it true that any $2$-connected $k$-regular vertex transitive graph with $k\geq 3$ is also $3$-connected (or possibly larger connectivity than $3$-connected)? If so, how would you show it or do you have a reference for it?

Indeed this is true. In fact, the following, stronger result, is known (see chapter 3 of the book Algebraic graph theory by Chris Godsil and Gordon Royle):

If $G$ is a $k$-regular vertex transitive graph, then $G$ is $\lceil \frac{2}{3}(k+1)\rceil$ connected.

In the special case where $k=3$, $\lceil \frac{2}{3}(k+1)\rceil = 3$. Moreover, this lower bound on the connectivity increases monotonically with $k$.
